# upload filename to database mysql from android

Tags: php, android, mysql, file-upload, upload

Hi I'm making an app for my internship and i got an error. 
please help me solve this

This is myactivity.java

```
private String SERVER_URL = "http://rarefactive-perfora.000webhostapp.com/crmobile/upload.php";

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intents
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go

        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.provider", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view.getId()==R.id.DateImp){
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
    if(view.getId()==R.id.select){
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if (view.getId()==R.id.b_upload){
        if (selectedFilePath != null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success upload file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                }
            }).start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please choose a file first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);  // Here photo file is the file EXTRA_OUTPUT location where you saved the actual camera image
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this, uri);
            Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:"+selectedFilePath);

            if (selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                tv_file_name.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot upload file to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
            if (data == null){
                return;
            }
            Bitmap bitmap1;
            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedFileUri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

                selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this, selectedFileUri);
                Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:"+selectedFilePath);

                if (selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                    tv_file_name.setText(selectedFilePath);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot upload file to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){
    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);

    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
        dialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv_file_name.setText("Source file doesn't exist: "+selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }else{
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("upload_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_file\";filename=\"" + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv_file_name.setText(fileName);
                    }
                });
            }
            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
}

Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final int PnT = PnTenv.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            final int CnF = CnFlist.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if (){
            //my validation
            }else{

                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                alertBuilder.setTitle("Message!");
                alertBuilder
                        .setMessage("Do you really want to Submit this Request?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                                final String PnTe = ((RadioButton) findViewById(PnT)).getText().toString();
                                final String CnFl = ((RadioButton) findViewById(CnF)).getText().toString();


                                Intent i = getIntent();

                                String cr_no = i.getStringExtra("cr_no");
                                String npk = i.getStringExtra("npk");
                                String cr_title = i.getStringExtra("cr_title");
                                String it_care_tick = i.getStringExtra("it_care_ticket");
                                String req_source = i.getStringExtra("request_source");
                                String req_type = i.getStringExtra("request_type");
                                String cr_date_req = i.getStringExtra("cr_date_req");
                                String brief_desc = i.getStringExtra("brief_desc");
                                String reason = i.getStringExtra("reason");
                                String sev_lvl = i.getStringExtra("severity_lvl");
                                String remark = i.getStringExtra("remark");

                                status.setText("Waiting for Supervisor");

                                RequestActivity2.InsertReq2 insertReq2 = new RequestActivity2.InsertReq2();
                                insertReq2.execute(cr_no, npk, cr_title, it_care_tick, req_source, req_type, cr_date_req, brief_desc, reason, sev_lvl, remark, DateImp.getText().toString(), HourI.getText().toString(), TimeI.getText().toString(), SystemI.getText().toString(), ScopeI.getText().toString(), ChangeObj.getText().toString(), PnTe, CnFl, checklist.getText().toString(), fallback.getText().toString(), tv_file_name.getText().toString(), status.getText().toString());
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), crRequestor.class));
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();

                alertDialog.show();

            }
        }
    });
}

private class InsertReq2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        String cr_no = args[0];
        String npk = args[1];
        String cr_title = args[2];
        String it_care_ticket = args[3];
        String request_source = args[4];
        String request_type = args[5];
        String cr_date_req = args[6];
        String brief_desc = args[7];
        String reason = args[8];
        String severity_lvl = args[9];
        String remark = args[10];
        String date_impact = args[11];
        String hour_impact = args[12];
        String time_impact = args[13];
        String system_impact = args[14];
        String scope_impact = args[15];
        String change_objective = args[16];
        String testing_piloting = args[17];
        String checklist_fallback = args[18];
        String checklist = args[19];
        String fallback = args[20];
        String upload_file = args[21];
        String status = args[22];

        ArrayList params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cr_no", cr_no));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("npk", npk));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cr_title", cr_title));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("it_care_ticket", it_care_ticket));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request_source", request_source));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request_type", request_type));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cr_date_req", cr_date_req));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("brief_desc", brief_desc));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reason", reason));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("severity_lvl", severity_lvl));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remark", remark));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_impact", date_impact));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hour_impact", hour_impact));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time_impact", time_impact));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("system_impact", system_impact));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope_impact", scope_impact));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("change_objective", change_objective));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testing_piloting", testing_piloting));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checklist_fallback", checklist_fallback));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checklist", checklist));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fallback", fallback));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("upload_file", upload_file));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);

        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is upload.php

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path.basename($_FILES['upload_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)){
    $result = array("result" => "success");
}else{
    $result = array("result" => "failed");
}

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

This is my output from phpmyadmin : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.user.appname/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170918_803639971.jpg

and i want my output is JPEG_20170918_803639971.jpg
please help me to solve this.

Comment: Wheres phpmyadmin come in?

Comment: Where are you adding the file name to mysql?

Comment: i have added the code to my post. pls check this